# Headline as the default description for an org-id link

Tags: org-mode, hyperlinks

I am using org-id to create links to different headlines in an org file. When using `org-insert-link` (`C-c C-l`), I select `id` as the link type option. Then I press RET. I have `:complete` configured to show a list of headlines from which I select the one I want, I use this:

```
(defun org-id-complete-link ()
  (concat "id:" (org-id-get-with-outline-path-completion org-refile-targets)))

(org-link-set-parameters "id" :complete #'org-id-complete-link)
```

Then I press RET and I am prompted for a description. I want the default description to be the headline I just selected from the complete menu. I have found that I can use `org-set-link-parameters` to specify a default string for this prompt, by using `:insert-description` followed by a string or a variable or a function. The problem is that I don't know how to use the headline I just selected as the default description.

I am testing this:

`(org-link-set-parameters "id" :insert-description "my default description")`

I want to replace the string with the headline.

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: For easily reproducing it, it would be nice if you could add the definition of your `org-id-complete-link` to the question. Anyway, I looked at it, and it seems to me that there is a bug in `org-insert-link`. Somewhere in that function there is a `(org-link-get-parameter type :insert-description)`, but it receives a type nil when using the `:complete` method, because in that case the `link` is set earlier to the value returned by the complete method (while it should be "id" for the org-link-get-parameter to return a non-nil value).

Comment: If you insert `(setq link (concat "id:" link))` just above the line `(let* ((type` just above that `(org-link-get-parameter type :insert-description)`, then the function defined as the value of `:insert-description` in your `org-link-parameters` will get called with a usable non-nil first argument (but the description will also include an `id:`). Of course it would be great if you could report this bug, possibly with a link to this comment :)

Comment: I'm not sure if that is a bug. I'm using ID links, which require some configuration to get working. This think this is similar to an `http:` link or a `file:` link, where you need to provide the description since there is no default (I might be wrong). The complete method I use provides the link for an ID; I'm wondering if the headline title can be obtained from this, but I have no idea how.